# Convert local .xlsx file to json using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning Javascript, currently I am trying my best to convert an excel to json to use as search data on a web page.

But I am unable to figure how to do that.

I have tried code snippets that are able to upload a file and convert, I am trying to convert that code into picking up a local file but facing the issue that "File is not a blob".

Due to my inexperience in JS this has become too daunting.
Please help.

P.S: Pure javascript code please, I can do it with node libraries as well but its just for a basic site.

Comment: Not without a library.  Zero chance.  The xlsx format is too complicated.

Comment: https://codepen.io/sharadjain/pen/MqPRPB 
Codepen like these are able to do it, I cannot even convert this code to pick the file locally instead of uploading. That's all I am looking for.

Comment: May I ask, what's the difference between *pick the file locally* with *uploading*  in your case? I think if you don't want to use Node backend, then you have to upload the file to the server (or, if you're running locally, the actions are the same IMO).

Comment: And you can provide the code you're working on, so we can help you to debug your code. Also add this Codepen snippet to your question via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69332324/edit) is helpful to other viewers.